# Differential amplifier circuit - output voltage

Tags: amplifier, differential

I have a homework problem.

> We have a differential amplifier circuit with two supply sources: \$V_{CC}=-V_{EE}=5V\$, that has two identical NPN transistors and three identical resistors. T2's base is connected to ground.
>
> 1. Draw the transfer characteristics of both outputs, if \$V_{IN1}\in<-1V;1V>\$
> 2. Draw \$V_{OUT1}(t), \ V_{OUT2}(t)\$ if \$V_{IN1}(t)=1\cdot\sin(2\pi\cdot100t)[V]\$
>
> \$V_{BE}=0.7V, \ V_{CE(sat)}=0.2V, \ \varphi_T=25mV\$

The circuit looks like this:

[image]

And \$R_{C1}=R_{C2}=R_E\$

Firstly: \$V_{OUT1(max)}=V_{OUT2(max)}=V_{CC}=5V\$

Now we need to calculate \$I_{EE}R_C\$: \$V_{IN2}-V_{BE}-I_{EE}R_E=V_{EE}\rightarrow I_{EE}R_E=I_{EE}R_C=0-0.7-(-5)=4.3V\$

Hence, \$V_{OUT2(min)}=V_{CC}-I_{EE}R_C=0.7V\$

And \$\overline{V_{OUT1}}=\overline{V_{OUT2}}=\frac{5+0.7V}{2}=2.85V\$

Now we need to calculate, when T1 becomes saturated:

\$V_{CC}-I_{EE}R_c-V_{CE(sat)}=V_{IN1(sat)}-V_{BE} \\ \\
V_{IN1(sat)}=5-4.3-0.2+0.7V=1.2V > 1V\$

so we do not have to care about saturation

The transfer characteristics look like this:

[image]
sorry for the lack of English here, but it is self-explanatory

Now, the outputs.

\$V_{OUT1}=\overline{V_{OUT1}}+V_{IN}\cdot G_{DM1}+V_{IN}\cdot G_{CM} \\ \\
V_{OUT2}=\overline{V_{OUT2}}+V_{IN}\cdot G_{DM2}+V_{IN}\cdot G_{CM} \\ \\
G_{DM1}=-\frac{g_mR_C}{2}=-\frac{I_{EE}R_C}{4\varphi_T}=-47V/V \\ \\
G_{DM2}=-G_{DM1} \\ \\
G_{CM}=-\frac{R_C}{2R_E}=-\frac{1}{2}V/V \$

So far so good (I hope)

The second output, \$V_{OUT2}(t)\$ is simple - it will be an amplified sinus oscillating around \$2.85V\$ and everything above \$5V\$ and below \$0.7V\$ will be limited by the power supply (i.e. will be cut off).

And now what I am struggling with: what will \$V_{OUT1}(t)\$ look like? I am not really sure how to interpret this "slope" for \$V_{IN}>2\varphi_T\$.

**Edit**
Here is the proper transfer characteristic, the previous one is incorrect

[image]

Comment: Does the math need some tanh(Vdiff), or hyperbolic tangent, in the expression?

Comment: @analogsystemsrf If you do the "full" calculation, yes indeed you would get a tanh(Vin_diff) curcve. But that's hard, it is easier to linearize the transfer around Vin_diff = 0 and draw limiting lines at the minimum and maximum Vout. That's what's done here.

Comment: @analogsystemsrf such linearization is good enough for my needs

Comment: For +1V  at the input T2 is cut-off but what about T1? The emitter current is Ie = (6V - 0.7V)/RE = 5.3V/RE the same current want to flow at the collector hence Vc = 5V - 5.3V = -0.3V.  This result tells us that the T2 is in the saturation region. You made an error by assuming that Iee is unchanged which not the case here. From there we see that the T1 enters the saturation region around 0.7V at the input.

Comment: Do you have any lecture notes about this topic in pdf?

Comment: @G36 Yea, you are right, T1 will be saturated for Vin>0.6V (assuming Vces=0.2V). I guess this is how I should calculate this voltage: Ie(sat)=Ic(sat)=(Vin(sat)-Vbe-Vee)/Re = (Vin(sat)+4.3V)/Re;;;;Vc=Vcc-Ic(sat)*Rc=-Vin(sat)+0.7V;;;Ve=Vin(sat)-0.7V;;;;Vce(sat)=Vc-Ve=1.4V-2Vin(sat)=0.2V -> Vin(sat)=0.6V \$

Comment: as for the notes, I do have lecture slides (in Polish); The one you might want to take a look at is W07
 https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B_hqDv0u6KMcQWxzWjdFZjJ6VTg

Comment: OK, now notice that for Vin >2*Vt you have CE amplifier (T1) with a gain of one and 180 degrees phase shift. But after the saturation, the T1 no longer inverts the signal. And Vc voltage will follow the emitter voltage Vc = Ve+Vce(sat). Do you have any lecture notes from Aleksander burd?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/81971/discussion-between-santaxl-and-g36).

Comment: @G36 I got a question - I realized that the drawing above is incorrect. In other words, what is the output voltage Vout2 for Vin<50mV? Because on the characteristic I wrote Ucc-IeeRc=0.7V, which - I think - is wrong, because this would apply that Uce=0V. But I have no idea how to calculate this

Comment: @SantaXL T2 emitter current is Ie2 = (5V- 0.7V)/RE and the same voltage drop we have across Rc2. VRc2 = 4.7V, and Vout2 = 0.3V